# ATG:Error while baseline indexing- Unable to process any CSF calls as the Credential Store server is not enabled

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo, oracle-commerce

I am getting the following error while doing baseline index of my Endeca application in ATG

```
15:26:47,891 ERROR [nucleusNamespace.atg.dynamo.security.opss.csf.CredentialStoreManager] (Thread-201) Unable to process any CSF calls as the Credential Store server i
s not enabled. Please check log for more details
15:26:47,913 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.commerce.search.StoreLocationOutputConfig] (Thread-201) Starting bulk load
15:26:47,915 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.commerce.endeca.index.CategoryToDimensionOutputConfig] (index-/atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin) Fa
iled to cancel incremental load of /atg/commerce/endeca/index/CategoryToDimensionOutputConfig, probably because no bulk load was running.
15:26:47,916 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.endeca.index.ConfigImportDocumentSubmitter] (Thread-203) Opening configuration repository connection for application logistore

15:26:47,917 ERROR [nucleusNamespace.atg.dynamo.security.opss.csf.CredentialStoreManager] (Thread-203) Unable to process any CSF calls as the Credential Store server i
s not enabled. Please check log for more details
15:26:47,916 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.commerce.search.ProductCatalogOutputConfig] (index-/atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin) Failed to can
cel incremental load of /atg/commerce/search/ProductCatalogOutputConfig, probably because no bulk load was running.
15:26:47,917 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.commerce.search.StoreLocationOutputConfig] (index-/atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin) Failed to canc
el incremental load of /atg/commerce/search/StoreLocationOutputConfig, probably because no bulk load was running.
15:26:47,919 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.endeca.index.ConfigImportDocumentSubmitter] (Thread-199) Opening configuration repository connection for application logistore

15:26:47,919 ERROR [nucleusNamespace.atg.dynamo.security.opss.csf.CredentialStoreManager] (Thread-199) Unable to process any CSF calls as the Credential Store server i
s not enabled. Please check log for more details
15:26:47,919 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.commerce.endeca.index.ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin] (Thread-203) Indexing process cancelled, Endeca says: Could not retri
eve workbench credential properties from credential store.
15:26:47,919 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.endeca.index.ConfigImportDocumentSubmitter] (Thread-207) Opening configuration repository connection for application logistore

15:26:47,920 ERROR [nucleusNamespace.atg.dynamo.security.opss.csf.CredentialStoreManager] (Thread-207) Unable to process any CSF calls as the Credential Store server i
s not enabled. Please check log for more details
15:26:47,921 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.commerce.endeca.index.ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin] (Thread-207) Indexing process cancelled, Endeca says: Could not retri
eve workbench credential properties from credential store.
```

After doing extensive research I found that C:\ATG\ATG11.2\home\servers\atg_production_lockserver\localconfig\atg\dynamo\server\OPSSInitializer.properties has path for jps-config.xml ie
JPSConfigurationLocation=C:/ATG/ATG11.2/home/../home/security/jps-config.xml
This jps-config.xml has some CSF related configuration.

How can I get rid of this error for successful baseline indexing.
I am stuck on this part.

Comment: Did you configure the administrator passwords using CIM?  Suggest you take a look at this support note from Oracle https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2075385.1

Comment: Yes I have referred to this link and did the same. I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you change the default workbench password. Simple solution would be, change Endeca experience manager password back to admin and try.

Otherwise, password needs to be changed in multiple places.

Thanks,
Ajay Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

Go to the OPSSInitializer component in dyn admin and check whether the path for jps-config.xml specified is correct there. If not, correct the path.